SQL create date time stamp
I am looking to see if there is a way to do this scenarios.
I don't have dates as to when someone opts out of our marketing emails but i was hoping that i could have a time stamp created for the date the client appears on the report. So if a new Client "Client 10" opts out it will show on the below report with a time stamp for the date they appeared and not have it change when a new person gets added.

